# How to identify h:message within a datatable?

Tags: jsf, datatable, message

I'm trying to place an error message beside a field in a datatable that it applies to, but I'm having trouble identifying it in the backing bean. I have an area on the top of my form for non-field-specific errors/info, but when the error is specific to a field (i.e. "email") I want the message to appear there.

This is my XHTML: (I've removed other non-relevant sections of the form for clarity)

```
<h:form styleClass="form" id="DeliveryOptionsForm">
   <h:dataTable value="#{sesh.delOptionList}" var="delOption">
      <h:outputText id="emailLabel" styleClass="#{(delOption.deliveryOption == 'EMAIL') ? '' : 'hide-field'}" value="Email  " />
      <h:message class="errorMessage" for="email" id="emailError" />
   </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This is my backing bean:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("DeliveryOptionsForm:email",
   new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Email address cannot be
   left blank when selecting email delivery.", null));
```

When I run the code, I get the error message:

```
[05/06/13 13:50:28:371 PDT] 00000026 RenderRespons W   There are some unhandled
FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
These unhandled FacesMessages are: 
- Email address cannot be left blank when selecting email delivery.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I have a feeling the clientId of the message is not being set properly.

Comment: Where's the email field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing validation in a backing bean action method. That's the wrong place to perform validation. You should be doing validation in a normal validator.

Use either JSF builtin validation:

```
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter foo" />
<h:message for="foo" />
```

Or use a custom validator wherein you throw `ValidatorException` with the desired message:

```
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" validator="fooValidator" />
<h:message for="foo" />
```

with

```
@FacesValidator("fooValidator")
public class FooValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        // ...

        if (!valid) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Fail!"));
        }
    }

}
```

Either way, it will automagically end up in the right message component.

---

You didn't state the concrete functional requirement anywhere and your code snippet is unfortunately incomplete, but I have the impression that you actually want to set `required="true"` only if another property has a certain value. In that case, just do for example:

```
required="#{delOption.deliveryOption == 'EMAIL'}"
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. While I was chatting with someone else about this, I said I can't use required="true" because it's only required if the drop down field is 'EMAIL'... then it hit me. DUH! Thanks for your reply. I love your tutorials. You really know your stuff.